# Scala Regex matching weird behaviour

Tags: regex, scala

Can someone explain why below prints `5 matches`

```
object RegExer extends App {
val PATTERN = """([5])""".r

print("5" match {
case PATTERN(string) => string + " matches!"
case _ => "No Match!"
})    
}
```

and this prints `No Match!`

```
object RegExer extends App {
val PATTERN = """[5]""".r

print("5" match {
case PATTERN(string) => string + " matches!"
case _ => "No Match!"
})    
}
```

Why does the range behaviour not work without parentheseis ?

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, you don't define a matching group. That's what the parentheses are used for in regex matching: they are defining what should be captured (and in this case, represented later as variables).

Answer (score 0):

You have explicitly required a pattern to return a single group: `PATTERN(string)`.

`string` here is for group (parentheseis in regex).

You should use `PATTERN()` for pattern without groups:

```
"5" match {
  case string @ PATTERN() => string + " matches!"
  case _ => "No Match!"
}
// String = 5 matches!
```